# How to create uniform gaps between states on an SVG map of the U.S.?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael, html5-canvas

My current project is a heat map of the United States:

http://up.massrelevance.com/cnbc/top-states/heatmap.html

Each state is its own Raphael object, and for the time being, I'm using a 2px white stroke for each state to represent its borders.

However, I'm trying to match a comp that has uniform gaps between - and a drop shadow behind - each state:

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s223/sh/00da56ce-658a-40f2-ae2f-b2b1c470f845/f4b490b7a409511974496b5d8beb7ffb

From a visual standpoint, I essentially need to change the white lines in my map to transparent/empty space so the shadow shows through.

Is there a relatively simple way to achieve this? My ideas so far:

- Long-shot wish, but use some sort of "negative" stroke, if it exists. A transparent stroke would simply be invisible, but a stroke that "cuts through" any paths/strokes/fills in layers below it to reveal the background would be a trivial fix.
- Remove the strokes and use Raphael's `transform` property with the [`.attr()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) method to scale each state down a small amount (e.g., 5%). I tried this and it worked reasonably well, but the caveat is that the states aren't symmetrical, so they scale based on a centerpoint that is usually not ideal (many states are shifted off-center and overlap each other slightly). That centerpoint can be changed, but that would involve a great deal of cumbersome trial & error for a large number of states.
- Simulate gaps between the states using a stroke color that matches the color of the drop shadow. This would be close enough, but the shadow-colored stroke around the top & left of the northern/western states would be a giveaway.

I would greatly appreciate any tips, ideas, or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like negative strokes in SVG. What you can do however, is to shrink the filled regions such that you get the gaps you need, and avoid using strokes.

You can use the experimental `Element.blur(amount)` method (requires SVG filter support, so doesn't work in Safari 5 or IE9). It should work just fine in all the other browsers though, including IE10.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. As I mentioned, though, shrinking the states to create gaps doesn't work well since they're not symmetrical objects; they're shrunk based on an off-center centerpoint, and thus shift in position slightly, enough to create non-uniform gaps (ex: http://bit.ly/PvV1Vo). Note the gaps around Louisiana; there's a large one between it and Texas, but almost none between it and Mississippi. I know that the centerpoint can be changed, but that would involve a ton of trial & error with each state just to get the gaps to line up evenly.